Ubuntu 22.04.4 - Microsoft teams not switching to already connected bluetooth
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish). I have tried using various Bluetooth headsets while attending my work calls on Microsoft Teams. The issue is whenever I start/join any meeting on teams (Bluetooth headphones are already connected)
The system uses only PC audio and microphones instead of Bluetooth headphones. After I manually power off and power on the PC's Bluetooth setting, it starts using Bluetooth headsets in the call. This happens with Bluetooth headphones of all the makes
I have tried so far. Please guide me on why this could happen and how to resolve this?
